# Equivalent to Regex.Replace in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

There is Regex in c# which I can use to remove some arbitrary characters or character ranges like `Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+", "", RegexOptions.Compiled)`. But what is the equivalent of that in C++. I know Boost has a regex library in it. But for this operation , is it viable and how performant it is ? What is the best and fast way to remove characters from a string in c++ ?

Comment: It's boost, you can't go that wrong, I would say

Comment: If you're really concerned about performance, use [Boost.Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/libs/xpressive/) (specifically, its static regexes) rather than Boost.Regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want [boost::regex_replace](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_replace.html) :

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <string>

const std::string input; 
boost::regex matcher("[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+");
const std::string formatter("");

std::string output = boost::regex_replace(input, matcher, formatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used Boost and found it both quick and easy to use. An example:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

bool detect_mypattern( const string& text )
{
    // A specific regex pattern
    static const boost::regex ep("[\\w\\s]{8}\\s{1}\\w{2}\\s{1}Test");
    return( boost::regex_match(text, ep) );
}
```

Of course, if you don't need the power of regex, there are plenty of string functions that can probably do a faster job of splicing characters out of a string.